# How to upload file through post request in Protractor TypeScript

Tags: typescript, http, npm, protractor, cucumber

I am working on Protractor, Typescript Cucumber Framework using "typed-rest-client/HttpClient" Package for getting the api response

I am stuck with how to post file (html file) in the post body by using http client. I am able to post some other data (String data) but not the file

Kindly share the steps or any other package use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one npm package available for rest assured api automation which is Frisby. It is based on javascript and you can send file using frisby. It is totally independent package and not associated with Protractor.

Comment: Thank you Ketan for your response. As per your suggestion https://docs.frisbyjs.com/api-and-usage/http worked .